# Calling specific instances of a docker service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, signalr, background-service

Not exactly sure how to ask this question or if this is a valid approach. So I am learning all about docker, containers, etc. From what I have read it is great for creating individual different microservices that perform various tasks such as BasketService, CartService, etc, which can each be contained in their own docker container on a vm which I think the URL calls from my UI (If hosted on a linux vm) would be something along the lines of https://MyLinuxVM/BasketService/{controller}.

**My Question:**

Now lets say I have only 1 service. We will call it MyService, that needs to have multiple instances. So I could have 4 instances i.e:  MyService1, MyService2, MyService3, MyService4. All exactly the same. From my client, would the following assumption be correct?

- I can call https://MyLinuxVM/MyService1/{controller} or https://MyLinuxVM/MyService2/{controller} to send to a specific container instance?

**Why:**

I feel this may help explain why I am doing this and possibly help everyone understand my problem in the first place. I have 4 physical devices I need to communicate with. We will call them Device1, Device2, Device3, Device4. Each device has its own IP Address, and its own set of "Tools" connected to it on various ports of the device (10-20 ports per device).

From our UI, the users can click a button that sets some torque values for the tool in their hand by sending the data to the MVC backend which gets sent to the "Correct" background worker/container which will then transform the data into byte[] and pass it along to its dedicated device. I am not sure if I need multiple background workers in a single container, or just a single configurable container with a single background worker that gets deployed multiple times dependent on number of devices we have running in the shop.

I have read a lot of things on creating different worker services that do different tasks, but I need multiple instances of a worker service that can be configured (preferably from db tables) to send to a specific device.

**Picture for additional details / visual:**

[image]

Comment: The two big things that jump out at me from this are that (a) Docker doesn't deal with URL paths at all [you can provide your own reverse proxy, but Docker makes this setup neither easier nor harder] and (b) Docker containers generally don't have access to hardware devices.  You could run the setup you describe with or without Docker, and Docker might help some of the deployment mechanics, but it's not obviously right or wrong.